# как записать значение в input box и отправить его node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Допустим, у меня есть ссылка какого-то сайта, в котором есть input box и кнопка подтверждения, а также есть их id. Как мне имея всё это сделать запрос и получить значение?

Comment: Посмотреть в какой форме этот инпут и какие ещё там есть элементы. Затем вручную сформировать запрос например: https://www.google.com/search?q={тут значение для поиска меняем}

Comment: запрос же не в гугл, мне нужно чтобы значение вводилось именно в импут бокс

Comment: Вы не поняли, не надо вводить в inputbox , а можно сформировать запрос, который будет после нажатия кнопки. Если нужно именно в inputbox, тогда Вам надо puppeteer. Ищите "puppeteer node js"